# Disabling/ignoring GCC/Clang error in Flycheck

Tags: flycheck

<sub>There is already a [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/13127/18592) on this but it's unanswered.</sub>

I'm writing a C++ header file that requires `libxml`, as seen below

```
#include <libxml2/libxml/xpath.h>
```

However Flycheck sees this as an error and consequently ignores any other potential error in the file.

```
In include /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xpath.h (c/c++-gcc)
```

How do I disable this error in Flycheck or at least configure it to recognize the rest of the errors in the file?

---

Here's my code:

```
#ifndef PATH_T_HPP
#define PATH_T_HPP

#include <string>
#include <libxml2/libxml/xpath.h>

namespace tw_lmm
{

  class path_t
  {
  public:
    /* Constructors */
    explicit path_t(const xmlKey*); // path only
    explicit path_t(const xmlKey*, const xmlKey*); // path, name
    explicit path_t(const xmkKey*, const xmkKey*, const xmkKey*); // path, name, extension

    explicit path_t(const path_t&);

    inline path_t operator=(const std::string&); // path only

    /* Destructors */
    virtual ~path_t();

    /* Getters */
    const inline std::string& path() const;
    const inline std::string& name() const;

  protected:
    std::string __path, __name, __extension;

  };

  const inline std::string& path_t::path() const
  {
    return __path;
  }

}

#endif
```

Note I misspelt `xmlKey` by writing `xmkKey`, Flycheck doesn't seem to recognise this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Sebastian Wiesner (lunaryorn)](https://github.com/lunaryorn) in Flycheck [issue #662](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/662),

> Flycheck does not have its own way to ignore warnings, but relies on syntax checker to be able to ignore warnings on their own.

I was able to add `"/usr/include/libxml2"` to variable `flycheck-gcc-include-path` using

```
M-x customize-variable RET flycheck-gcc-include-path
```

an insert a new entry.